# SQL error Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: sql, jsp, jdbc

Am I missing an error with the following to insert into a table with four columns, message_id (auto-incremented) message_sender, message_reciever, message_body. I have checked similar questions and haven't found the solution.
'''

```
        <% String sender_id = request.getParameter("message_sender");
        String reciever_id = request.getParameter("message_reciever");
        String message = request.getParameter("message_body");

        try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/fyp", "root", "Kmd116352323!");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();

        st.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO messages(message_sender,message_reciever,message_body) VALUES('"+sender_id+", "+reciever_id+" , "+message+" ')");

        out.println("Your request has been noted."
                + " Please return to your user profile or log out");

        } catch(Exception e){
        out.println(e);
                }
        %>
```

Comment: You use a variable named `receiver_id` of type `String`, but the name suggests a numeric identifier ... out of context, but useful: use `PreparedStatement` in order to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Please [learn to properly use a PreparedStament](https://mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/). Do not concatenate user input into a SQL string. If you do that, your problem will most probably go away as well

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but that code shouldn't be inside a JSP, but a servlet that uses a connection pool, rather than hardcoding the connection string in the presentation layer

Answer (score 1):

You should not concatenate values into a query string. It makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection, or mistakes like forgetting quotes around values. The specific problem in your case is that you have a quote before the first value and a quote after the last value, which makes it a single value instead of three separate values.

However, instead of fixing the immediate problem by adding those missing quotes, you should switch to using a prepared statement:

```java
try (PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(
        "INSERT INTO messages(message_sender,message_reciever,message_body) VALUES(?, ?, ?)") {
    pstmt.setString(1, sender_id);
    pstmt.setString(2, reciever_id);
    pstmt.setString(3, message);

    pstmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

As an aside, you really should not put data access in a JSP. It belongs in a DAO or service class.

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect:

```
VALUES('"+sender_id+", "+reciever_id+" , "+message+" ')
```

You have a `'` wrapping the all the values... Which means sql will think you are only sending 1 value. If they are all text values it should be like this:

```
VALUES('"+sender_id+"', '"+reciever_id+"' , '"+message+"')
```

If you know some of the values are of INT type then you do not need the `'` for that value:

```
VALUES("+sender_id+", "+reciever_id+" , '"+message+"')
```

Text values need to be wrapped with a `'`

Comment: The better solution would be to use a prepared statement.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel absolutely. But one step at a time... He shouldnt be doing this via scriptlets either.

Comment: True, however, I think it is important to educate people about not using concatenated query strings and the security implications of this are far more important than using scriptlets or not.

Comment: yup, it's worth informing him of that.